# Establish conditions on initial data of the following first order PDE ( characteristics method)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, regularity-theory-of-pdes, characteristics

> Consider the first order PDE

> \begin{cases}
> u_x + u_y = u^2 \\
> u(x,0)=v(x)
> \end{cases}

for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y>0$. For which functions $v \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ does exists a solution $u(x,y) \in C^1(\mathbb{R} \times [0,\infty))$ ?

---

I applied the method of characteristics to the equation above, and found:

$$u(x,y)=\frac{v(x-y)}{1 - v(x-y) y}$$

How can I estabilish some conditions on $v$? I would just say that it's sufficient to have $$v(x-y) y < 1$$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y >0$, but I don't know if it is what expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is sufficient. But remark that if $v(\cdot)$ is bounded, then your condition $v(x-y)y < 1$ is locally valid on some interval $y\in [0,\delta)$. For example if $v(x) \equiv 1$, then
$$u(x,y) = \frac{1}{1-y}$$
Which solves
$$u_y =u_x+u_y= u^2, \ u(x,0) = 1$$
This is actually an ODE in $y$ (so you can apply uniqueness and existence theorems) and it is easy to see that the solution blows up at $y=1$ and is therefore only valid on $[0,1)$ (if we only consider $y\geq 0$). Just like non-linear ODEs, non-linear PDEs can also have a finite blow up time.

Comment: Thanks for the check. Anyway, I still can't understand what should be the proper answer to the question

Comment: It would be exactly as you said. "There exists $u\in C^1(\mathbb{R};[0,\infty))$ solving the problem as long as the initial data $v\in C^1(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$ is given such that $v(x-y)y < 1$ for each $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}\times [0,\infty)$". Any solution which does not satisfy this will not be differentiable whenever $f(x,y) :=v(x-y)y = 1$. Given that $f(x,0) = 0$ and $f\in C^\infty$, it follows $f(x,y)<1$ on some interval $[0,\delta)$, but not necessarily on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Now it's clear, thanks! :)